# Awk: Cannot concatenate strings

Tags: linux, awk, concatenation

I'm currently dealing with AWK, and I have three variables I work with:

- $0 variable - for this example it's equivalent to:

`path/filename.cpp LOG_ERR << "error in this log" << e.what();`

- $logName variable - I parsed out the name of the cpp file, namely:

`filename`

- $2 variable - contains the default second value:

`LOG_ERR`

**Question:**

What I'm trying to do is concatenate values like so:

`logName=$logName $2;`

But instead of the expected value `filenameLOG_ERR`, I get this:

`filename LOG_ERR << "error in this log" << e.what();`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: AWK code as requested:

```
awk '{
logName=sub(/^.*\//,"",$1);
logName=sub(/\..*:/,"",$logName);

print $logName;
print $2;

logName=$logName $2;

print $logName;
}' $file
```

EDIT2: Fixed. Never call on any $ variables in awk unless it's a field number. :)

```
awk '{
logName=$1;
sub(/^.*\//,"",logName);
sub(/\..*:/,"",logName);
print logName;
logName=logName $2;
print logName;
}' $file
```

Comment: show us your awk code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logName=$logName $2;
```

this code is wrong.

you used `$logName`, which means column index `logName`, obviously it is not what you want.

If the value of `logName` is string `filename`, awk will try to get column 
`$filename` here,  if variable was not defined/assigned, and you try to get it as number, awk would get `0`. you can test this:

```
kent$ echo "xxxx y y"|awk '{print $foo}'
xxxx y y
```

so I guess, the fix would be: (if `logName` was set right value, as you said)

```
logName=logName $2;
```

**EDIT**

you should never call `$logName` check this example:

```
kent$echo "111 222"|awk -v logName="filename" '{logName=logName $2;print logName}'                                                                             
filename222
```

Comment: Incorrect. Calling print on $logName after `logName=logName $2;` only prints out `filename`. :/

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. if I were you, I would get the string in this way: `awk -F'\\.cpp |/| ' '{print $2$3}'`

Comment: Won't work, I have about 20 lines in the $0 format mentioned above. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. 20 or 2k lines are not the problem at all. anyway, I hope you understood the problem in your codes. There should **NO** `$logName` in your code. good luck.